# Excel 2007 ODBC data populates when opened via Windows Explorer, but not when opened via Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, odbc, vba

I have an Excel 2007 workbook that contains an ODBC data connection (to FoxPro, if that matters). The connection is set to "refresh data when opening the file."

When I go into File Explorer and open the workbook, the data populates into the spreadsheet as it should. However, when I execute a function in Access VBA that opens the workbook, the data from the ODBC connection does not populate.

Why would it make a difference which way the workbook is opened? And more importantly, how can I get the data to populate when the workbook is opened via Access VBA?

Here is the Access VBA code that opens the workbook:

```
Public Sub Subform_cmdOpenFile_Click(frm As Form)

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim ftiSuperclass As FilingTemplateInterface

Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone

If (rs.BOF Or rs.EOF) Then GoTo PROC_EXIT

Set ftiSuperclass = New FilingTemplateInterface
ftiSuperclass.ShowWorkbook rs!Directory & frm!Filename

PROC_EXIT:
On Error Resume Next
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
ftiSuperclass.QuitExcel
Set ftiSuperclass = Nothing
Exit Sub

PROC_ERROR:
Resume PROC_EXIT
End Sub


Friend Sub ShowWorkbook(strFilename As String)
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim appExcel As New Excel.Application
appExcel.Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilename, AddToMRU:=True
appExcel.visible = True
Set appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding the line of code noted below, to force connection refresh on open:

```
Friend Sub ShowWorkbook(strFilename As String)   
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject   
Dim appExcel As New Excel.Application   
appExcel.Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFilename, AddToMRU:=True  
appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").Refresh 'added this line
appExcel.visible = True   
Set appExcel = Nothing   
End Sub
```